# Get required data from multiple table using DRF Serializers

Tags: python, django, serialization

i am new to DRF serializers,i am facing small problem here...

models.py

```
class roles(models.Model):
    role        =   models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    type    =   models.CharField(max_length = 20) 
    one         =   models.CharField(max_length = 20) 
    class Meta:
        db_table    =   'roles'

class employees(models.Model):
    name     =   models.CharField(max_length=25)
    mobileno =   models.IntegerField()
    roletype =   models.ForeignKey(roles,related_name='emps')   
    class Meta:
        db_table    =   'employees'
```

serializers.py

```
class rSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = roles
        fields = ('type','one')

class eSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = employees
        fields = ('name','mobileno')
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def accesstwo(request):  
    if request.method == 'GET':
       #emp = employees.objects.all()
       #serializer = eSerializer(emp, many=True)
       #return JSONResponse({"resource":serializer.data}) 

       emp = employees.objects.get(id = 1)
       serializer = eSerializer(emp, many=False)
       return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

if i run the above code,i am getting the result like below.

```
{
  "name": "emp01",
  "mobileno": 23434
},
```

But here i want to get the the data from the both the tables using serializers like below.

```
{
  "name": "emp01",
  "mobileno": 23434,
  "type":"manager",
  "one":"test"
}
```

how to do this in python DRF services ?.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass `rSerializer()` in `eSerializer()` . Please check the updated code as mentioned below:

```
class eSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    roles = rSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = employees
        fields = ('name','mobileno', 'roles')
```